# bootstrap grid creation for blocks with multiple columns and rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]How do I create the grid that I describe in the image with bootstrap? The problem in my eyes is that you cannot dissect the image in smaller squares that allow you to use the nesting functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class='col-sm-2' style='height:210px;'>
    <div class='col-xs-12' style='background: red; height:100%'></div>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-10' style='height:100px; margin-bottom: 10px'>
    <div class='col-xs-12' style='background: red; height:100%'></div>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-3' style='height:100px'>
    <div class='col-xs-12' style='background: red; height:100%'></div>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-7' style='height:600px'>
   <div class='col-xs-12' style='background: red; height:100%'></div>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-5' style='height: 490px; top:-490px;'>
    <div class='col-xs-12' style='background: red; height:100%'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks user1794125! I thought about moving the last column up but was wondering whether I was overlooking an alternative. I guess I just go for this solution. Thanks again!